# Sending Multiple images from web service SPRINGBOOT+REST+MAVEN

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-boot

I am writing a web service in spring boot restful web App using which i am sending a image to anyone who wants to consume it below is a code snippet which worked for me

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/photo_1",method = RequestMethod.GET )  
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> greeting_image_1(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) throws IOException{
    InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/someimage.jpg");       
    byte[] a = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG); 
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(a,headers,HttpStatus.CREATED);            
}
```

This web service works perfectly fine in case i want to return a single image from a web service

But what if in case i want to return array of images(i.e. more than 1 image)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: May be ResponseEntity<List<Byte[]>> should help?

Comment: @JaganathanNanthakumar I tried with it,but when i send single image i can see that in browser when i hit the url (localhost:8080/photo_1) in browser after deploying App , when i use ResponseEntity<List<Byte[]>>  for sending multiple images i don't see anything in browser though i can see byte array in string when printed with syso but i am not sure whether consumer will be able to consume it.

Comment: I guess I am wrong. I thought Spring would do the job of converting list of byte arrays to a multipart response. But it does not. You need to send just a single byte array as a multipart response that contains all the images with proper boundaries set in between. Regarding consumption of data, I am doubtful if it can be displayed as such without processing the response.

Comment: I've added a method in my post that helps you to construct multipart response containing multiple images. Please use the byte[] returned by this method in your ResponseEntity and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the sample code that I wrote to generate a multipart response with multiple images in it. It's properly consumed by Firefox and it prompts to save each image in the response.

```
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> showImages () throws IOException {
    String boundary="---------THIS_IS_THE_BOUNDARY";
    List<String> imageNames = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"1.jpg","2.jpg"});
    List<String> contentTypes = Arrays.asList(new String[]{MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE,MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE});
    List<Byte[]> imagesData = new ArrayList<Byte[]>();
    imagesData.add(ArrayUtils.toObject(IOUtils.toByteArray(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/1.jpg"))));
    imagesData.add(ArrayUtils.toObject(IOUtils.toByteArray(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/2.jpg"))));
    byte[] allImages = getMultipleImageResponse(boundary, imageNames,contentTypes, imagesData);
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Content-Type","multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=" + boundary);
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(allImages,headers,HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

private static byte[] getMultipleImageResponse(String boundary, List<String> imageNames, List<String> contentTypes, List<Byte[]> imagesData){
    byte[] finalByteArray = new byte[0];
    Integer imagesCounter = -1;
    for(String imageName : imageNames){
        imagesCounter++;
        String header="--" + boundary 
                + "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + imageName
                + "\"; filename=\"" + imageName + "\"\r\n"
                + "Content-type: " + contentTypes.get(imagesCounter) + "\r\n\r\n";
        byte[] currentImageByteArray=ArrayUtils.addAll(header.getBytes(), ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(imagesData.get(imagesCounter)));
        finalByteArray = ArrayUtils.addAll(finalByteArray,ArrayUtils.addAll(currentImageByteArray, "\r\n\r\n".getBytes()));
        if (imagesCounter == imageNames.size() - 1) {
            String end = "--" + boundary + "--";
            finalByteArray = ArrayUtils.addAll(finalByteArray, end.getBytes());
        }
    }
    return finalByteArray;
}
```

You should implement this depending on the capability of the consumer. If the consumer can parse multipart response, please go ahead with this approach, else consider other options like

1. Sending a zipped file of all images
2. Returning a json/xml of image names along with URLs to download them
3. Returning a json/xml with all images in Base64 encoded string

You may also send a html response with all images embedded in it using the below code. This should work fine in all browsers as it is pure html.

```
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getAllImages() throws IOException {
    List<String> imageNames = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"1.jpg","2.jpg"});
    List<String> contentTypes = Arrays.asList(new String[]{MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE,MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE});
    List<Byte[]> imagesData = new ArrayList<Byte[]>();
    imagesData.add(ArrayUtils.toObject(IOUtils.toByteArray(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/1.jpg"))));
    imagesData.add(ArrayUtils.toObject(IOUtils.toByteArray(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/2.jpg"))));
    byte[] htmlData=getHtmlData(imageNames,contentTypes, imagesData);
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(htmlData,headers,HttpStatus.OK);
}

private static byte[] getHtmlData(List<String> imageNames, List<String> contentTypes, List<Byte[]> imagesData){
    String htmlContent="<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Images</title></head><body>";
     Integer imagesCounter = -1;
    for(String imageName : imageNames){
         imagesCounter++;
        htmlContent = htmlContent + "<br/><br/><b>" + imageName + "</b><br/></br/><img src='data:" + contentTypes.get(imagesCounter) + ";base64, " + org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64
                .encodeBase64(ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(imagesData.get(imagesCounter)))) + "'/>";
    }
    htmlContent = htmlContent + "</body></html>";
    return htmlContent.getBytes();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.It worked in firefox but can u suggest what can be done to get it work on chrome?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, different browsers handle multipart response differently. If you would like to have a consistent behaviour consider sending a html response with embedded images. I've updated my post with code for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to **"Uploading Files" Spring Boot guide** : https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

There's a an example of upload and download.