# Java 8 REST API - Return List of Images from Server

Tags: java, image, api, rest

I am trying to return a list of images (List<byte[]>) from an API endpoint and get the following error:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

To return a single image from the API, I have the following method that works fine:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getImage/{imageId}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public byte[] getImage(@PathVariable("imageId") String imageId) throws IOException {
    final Optional<ImageModel> retrievedImage = imageRepository.findById(Long.valueOf(imageId));

    ImageModel img = new ImageModel(retrievedImage.get().getName(), retrievedImage.get().getType(),
            decompressBytes(retrievedImage.get().getPicByte()));
    
    return img.getPicByte();
}
```

However, I am now looking for something similar but rather than return 1 image, I want to return all images related to the productId. The Database side is all setup correctly, but I get the error previously mentioned when trying to call the following endpoint:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getImage/{productId}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public List<byte[]> getImagesForProduct(@PathVariable("productId") int productId) throws IOException {
    final Optional<List<ImageModel>> retrievedImages = imageRepository.getByProductId(String.valueOf(productId));
    
    List<ImageModel> imageModelList = retrievedImages.get();
    List<byte[]> response = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
    
    imageModelList.forEach(image -> {
        response.add(image.getPicByte());
    });
    
    return response;
}
```

From my understanding when using `MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE` this tells the browser how to display the bytes correctly (Which it does) but is there anything similar for returning a list of images?

I have tried creating a wrapper class so that I can return the imageBytes & imageName together as follows:

```
public class ProductImageResponse {

private String productName;

private byte[] imageBytes;

public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}

public byte[] getImageBytes() {
    return imageBytes;
}

public void setImageBytes(byte[] imageBytes) {
    this.imageBytes = imageBytes;
}
}


    @GetMapping(value = "/getImage/{imageId}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public List<ProductImageResponse> getImagesForProduct(@PathVariable("productId") String productId) throws IOException {
    final Optional<List<ImageModel>> retrievedImages = imageRepository.getByProductId(productId);
    
    List<ImageModel> imageModelList = retrievedImages.get();
    List<ProductImageResponse> response = new ArrayList<ProductImageResponse>();
    
    imageModelList.forEach(image -> {
        ProductImageResponse productImageResponse = new ProductImageResponse();
        productImageResponse.setProductName(image.getName());
        productImageResponse.setImageBytes(image.getPicByte());
    });
    
    return response;
}
```

But i get the same error.

Comment: This will not work by default in spring, check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38356002

Comment: Yes, @YuvarajG is absolutely right. In your working method you tell spring that method produces  IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE, but when you try to return list of images then response contains list of byte[] too.